# Running imagemagick convert with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder, imagemagick-convert

I want to run the following command on Windows command prompt:

`convert -density 50 -pointsize 70 -font Arial label:"Text with spaces" output.gif`

This command uses imagemagick and makes a gif file with the text "Text with spaces" and saves it to output.gif

This works nicely straight from Windows 7 command prompt. Now, I want to run this command from a Java application of mine. Consider:

```
private void runConvert()
{
    try
    {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("convert","-density","50","-pointsize","70"
        ,"font","Arial","label:","\"Text with spaces\"","output.gif");

        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = pb.start();
        BufferedReader inStreamReader = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        while(inStreamReader.readLine() != null){
            System.out.println(inStreamer.readLine());
        }

     } catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Problem is, this makes `convert` echo:

```
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitue.c/ReadImage/501
```

If I try to use `runConvert` function with a text parameter that has no spaces, like "BurgerKing" it works like a charm. How can I fix it for multi spaces parameters?

Comment: I recommend to use [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/)  It is reliable interface library to execute ImageMagick operations.

Comment: You are missing a '-' in front of your "font" argument. It explains your error if that is not a typo.

Comment: @dlemstra that's a typo here

Answer (score 0):

You should specify *label:* and *"Text with spaces"* as a single argument:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("convert","-density","50","-pointsize",
"70","-font","Arial","label:\"Text with spaces\"","output.gif");
```

Comment: Have you tried this? convert echos nothing but there's no file output.

Comment: Did you check the working directory of your application for the file output.gif? Your file might be written to a different location on your disk then what you are expecting.

Comment: Checked. Also changed it into a known directory by changing `output.gif` to `c:\\testings\\output.gif`.

Comment: Did you also check the output from process.getErrorStream?